# How to separate a string with duplicated characters

Tags: c++, string, split, c++14

I am trying to split string. For example, if I enter `Shooby Dooby by the Wooby Sisters`, the function should split the string so that the result will be

```
Title: Shooby Dooby
Artist: the Wooby Sisters
```

but what I get from my code is

```
Title: Shoo
Artist: Sisters
```

My code is

```
string getArtistStr(string fName){
    string retVal = fName;
    if (fName.length() > 0){
        int pos = fName.find_last_of(" by ");
        if (pos != string::npos){
            retVal = fName.substr(pos+1);
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

string getTitleStr(string fName){
    string retVal = fName;
    int pos = fName.find_first_of(" by ");
    if (pos != string::npos){
        retVal = fName.substr(0,pos);
    }
    return retVal;
}
cout << "Title: " << getTitleStr(fullName) << endl;
cout << "Artist: " << getArtistStr(fullName) << endl << endl;
```

Where went wrong?

Comment: See the docs for `.find_last_of`. I think it finds the last occurrence of *any* of the provided characters.

Comment: Are you sure the input works as it should? If you want our help you have to give us a [mcve]. Otherwise you need to *debug* the program on your own (e.g. by using a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement).

Comment: This `retVal` technique is counter-productive and a bad habit. You're assigning, which makes a copy, then stomping it, making *another* copy, and then returning that, which makes yet another copy. It's best to just `return` what you want directly, like either `return fName.substr(pos+1)` or `return fName` if that other block doesn't fire.

Comment: Since you spend all this effort finding your target to split at, why not return a `std::tuple` or `std::pair` of strings so you can do this in one shot?

Comment: You probably mean to use [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) as in `fName.find(" by ")`

Comment: @tadman and [`rfind()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind)

Comment: @RemyLebeau This whole exercise makes wild assumptions about what band names and song titles have in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string DELIMITER = " by ";

string getArtistStr(const string& fName){
    string retVal = fName;
    if (fName.length() > 0){
        // Searches the string for the first occurrence of the delimiter
        int pos = fName.find(DELIMITER);
        if (pos != string::npos){
            // Incrementing the position to read after the occurrence of the delimiter
            retVal = fName.substr(pos+DELIMITER.length());
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}

string getTitleStr(const string& fName){
    string retVal = fName;
    // Searches the string for the first occurrence of the delimiter
    int pos = fName.find(DELIMITER);
    if (pos != string::npos){
        retVal = fName.substr(0,pos);
    }
    return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    string fullName = "Shooby Dooby by the Wooby Sisters";
    cout << "Title: " << getTitleStr(fullName) << endl;
    cout << "Artist: " << getArtistStr(fullName) << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: It's great including working code, but `bits/stdc++` is a real problem. It's non-portable and also a bad habit to get into.